# custom Bitmap size ( inSampleSize * inSampleSize) of a bitmap android

Tags: android

I am having a bitmap I want to apply "`inSampleSize = 8`" on it. but everywhere I am getting code where `inSampleSize` is being applied to `resource image`. Is there any way?

**Update:**
`BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap blurredBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),options );`

As suggested by *@Hind* I am applying that. But it gives error that you *int* is required and you are passing *Option* .

Comment: what u need exactly..? explain breafly..

Comment: What about another way? Just clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

yes man , you can create a options and put inSampleSize=8, and after put Options into this method

```
public Bitmap ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, width, height, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

BitmapFactory.Options are used when you create a bitmap with any of the methods of the BitmapFactory class. They are not applicable to the method ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail. The only option this method accepts is [OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT)